# How to cache results

Tags: mysql, caching

I heard that a lot of big project administrators caches results. I wonder how do I do it? Thanks

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Insufficient information for useful answer. The MySQL query cache is well documented and many people have opinions on their blogs about how useful it is (not).

Comment: Are you talking about cacheing queries? or about cacheing results?

Comment: woah sorry, cacheing results, i'll edit my post

Comment: In time you'll have a big project of your own, you'll know it for sure. And also when you have to use caching and when don't. And why database tuning should be going first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-logic:

```
Test if query result exists in cache
If so,
    retrieve from cache 
    return result
else   
    execute query against database   
    transfer results to an array, list or object(s) [dependent on language]
    store results in cache (serialize if necessary)
    return result
```

Often memcache or APC (if you're using PHP) can be used to store the cache, but files can be used at a pinch. Code will vary depending on what medium you're using for cacheing

Answer (score 0):

In a tipical mysql - php environment memcached can be a good choice.

[memcached FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ)